# c# array in prime numbers - Where is my mistake?

Tags: c#

//I want to fill an array with the first 15 prime numbers. the loop will only increase as you find the prime number and add it to the array.

```
 int[] primes = new int[15];
    int j = 0;
    int i = 2;
    while (j < 15)
    {
        if (IsPrime(i))
        {
            primes[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < primes.Length; a++)
    {
        Console.Write(primes[a] + " ");
    }
}

//method

static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that the `IsPrime()` function is returning the value you expect?

Comment: I understand now, but after checking the if block, I don't quite understand why it should be false. I would be glad if you explain.

Comment: If the number being tested is divisible by another number, then it is not prime, i.e. return false. (A common optimisation is to only test up to Math.Sqrt(number to test).)

Comment: Yeah, let's start with `i=2` in your IsPrime method. Given the number 4, which is not a prime, will your IsPrime method return false or true? Of course true despite 4 not being a prime, because `4 % 2 == 0`...

Comment: Now I understand the logic better. thank you.

Comment: PS. Replace the second loop with `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", primes.Select(x=>x.ToString())));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your `IsPrime` function is actually doing the exact oposite of what you want to achieve. Look at that function again and think about where the mistake is (hint: it is a minor problem, I feel like you just overlooked something and that the logic in your mind was correct).

After you get the result you want, I also recommend you to think about `IsPrime` function again and try to optimize it a little bit (hint: do you really need to test all the numbers, one by one?) and also to your `while` loop (hint: do you really need to iterate `i` by `1`?).

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the `IsPrime` function as follows:

```
static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    int i;  
    for (i = 2; i <= number - 1; i++)  
    {  
        if (number % i == 0)  
        {
            return false;  
        }  
    }  
    if (i == number)  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    return false; 
}
```

Output

`2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47`